# how to rewrite when url contain null char in nginx

Tags: null, nginx, url-rewriting

Here I have a problem about rewrite url when url contain null char in nginx.

For example, the get url is

```
http://localhost/test/\x02x00/
```

if `\x00` occur in url, nginx will return 400 bad request.

I try this rewrite rule but looks doesn't work.

```
rewrite "/test/\x02\x00/"  /new/
```

However if I remove `\x00` everything works fine.

Anyone has any idea about this situation?

Answer (score 0):

URL cannot contain null characters according to RFC.

Comment: No. Don't do that. http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2012-July/034627.html

Comment: The NULL charter in request line completely breaks HTTP protocol at the earliest stage. You can't do any request processing with such error. Actually, it doesn't even the HTTP request.

Comment: yes, but here my problem is uri contain null char and request again and again due to it return 400. Any idea how to stop request if uri contain null char?

Comment: Have no idea, since this is not a valid HTTP in any way, you should look for the solution outside of web-server. May be `iptable` will be suitable.